# Regarding Derived Column transformation in SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have an Excel file with `first_name`, `last_name`, `location` as source. In destination I've `first_name`, `last_name`, `location` and `status`

In the SSIS ETL process, I need to pass the default value "Current" for the `status` column. How do I configure this in a Derived Column Transformation when that `status` column is not available in the source?

Answer (score 0):

In the Derived Column transformation, you can select 'Add as new column' in the second column (named "Derived column"). This setting determines whether an existing column is overridden or a new one is added.

So, enter "Status" as the `Derived Column name`, set `Derived Column` to `Add as new column` and enter "Current" in the `Expression` field. SSIS will automatically assign a data type to it. If you specifically need `NVARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR`, you can change the expression to

```
(DT_WSTR, 7)"Current"
```

This adds a cast to NVarchar.